# How to update item in RecyclerView after it finished its animation?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using a recyclerView to show all the entries from my database in a nice way. I added class SwipeToDeleteCallback to provide the ability to delete item from the recyclerView. When item deletes, recyclerview raises next items upward.

Each item contains 2 textViews that update in onBindViewHolder() in adapter for recyclerView. The problem is when I delete some item, the last item appeared on the screen doesn't show these textViews correctly. I already tried adapter.notifyItemChanged() and view.postInvalidate() but it doesn't help.

It seems that if recyclerView tries to update values of its child during the animation, it produces such error. I'm not sure if I'm right.

[Screenshot: After deleting a few previous item two last items doesn't appear properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH9II.png)

DictionaryActivity.kt:

```
class DictionaryActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var coordinatorLayout : CoordinatorLayout
    private lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView
    private lateinit var dictionaryAdapter: DictionaryAdapter
    private lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.dictionary)

        coordinatorLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.dictionaryCoordinatorLayout) as CoordinatorLayout
        recyclerView = findViewById<View>(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView

        // Create adapter passing in the sample user data
        dictionaryAdapter = DictionaryAdapter(Database.getAllEntries(this))
        // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
        recyclerView.adapter = dictionaryAdapter
        // Set layout manager to position the items
        linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        enableSwipeToDeleteAndUndo()
    }

    private fun enableSwipeToDeleteAndUndo() {
        val swipeToDeleteCallback: SwipeToDeleteCallback = object : SwipeToDeleteCallback(this) {
            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, i: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val entry: Entry = dictionaryAdapter.entries[position]
                dictionaryAdapter.removeEntry(position)
                val snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(
                        coordinatorLayout,
                        "Item was removed from the list.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                    )
                snackbar.setAction("UNDO") {
                    dictionaryAdapter.restoreEntry(entry, position)
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)
                }
               
                snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
                snackbar.show()
            }
        }
        val itemTouchhelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeToDeleteCallback)
        itemTouchhelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
    }
}
```

SwipeToDeleteCallback.java:

```
abstract public class SwipeToDeleteCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    Context mContext;
    private Paint clearPaint;
    private ColorDrawable background;
    private int backgroundColor;
    private Drawable deleteDrawable;
    private int intrinsicWidth;
    private int intrinsicHeight;


    SwipeToDeleteCallback(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        background = new ColorDrawable();
        backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#b80f0a");
        clearPaint = new Paint();
        clearPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        deleteDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_delete);
        intrinsicWidth = deleteDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        intrinsicHeight = deleteDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();


    }


    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return makeMovementFlags(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        int itemHeight = itemView.getHeight();

        boolean isCancelled = dX == 0 && !isCurrentlyActive;

        if (isCancelled) {
            clearCanvas(c, itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            return;
        }

        background.setColor(backgroundColor);
        background.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + (int) dX, itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
        background.draw(c);

        int deleteIconTop = itemView.getTop() + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2;
        int deleteIconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2;
        int deleteIconLeft = itemView.getRight() - deleteIconMargin - intrinsicWidth;
        int deleteIconRight = itemView.getRight() - deleteIconMargin;
        int deleteIconBottom = deleteIconTop + intrinsicHeight;


        deleteDrawable.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconRight, deleteIconBottom);
        deleteDrawable.draw(c);

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);


    }

    private void clearCanvas(Canvas c, Float left, Float top, Float right, Float bottom) {
        c.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, clearPaint);

    }

    @Override
    public float getSwipeThreshold(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return 0.7f;
    }
}
```

DictionaryAdapter.java:

```
public class DictionaryAdapter  extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<DictionaryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // Provide a direct reference to each of the views within a data item
    // Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Your holder should contain a member variable
        // for any view that will be set as you render a row
        private final TextView wordRussianTextView;
        private final  TextView wordHebrewTextView;

        private final  ProgressBar progressBar;
        private final  ImageButton editButton;

        // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
        // and does the view lookups to find each subview
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
            // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
            super(itemView);

            wordRussianTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            wordHebrewTextView = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
            editButton  = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        }
    }

    private List<Entry> entries;

    // Pass in the contact array into the constructor
    public DictionaryAdapter(List<Entry> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    // Usually involves inflating a layout from XML and returning the holder
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DictionaryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_element, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(contactView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    // Involves populating data into the item through holder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DictionaryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Get the data model based on position
        Entry entry = entries.get(position);

        // Set item views based on your views and data model
        holder.wordRussianTextView.setText(entry.getWord(Entry.LANGUAGE.RUSSIAN));
        holder.wordHebrewTextView.setText(entry.getWord(Entry.LANGUAGE.HEBREW));
        holder.progressBar.setProgress(entry.getProgress());


        Log.e("onBindViewHolder", "New item:");
        Log.e("onBindViewHolder", "russian : " + holder.wordRussianTextView.getText());
        Log.e("onBindViewHolder", "hebrew : " + holder.wordHebrewTextView.getText());
        Log.e("onBindViewHolder", "--------------------------------");

        //holder.wordRussianTextView
    }

    // Returns the total count of items in the list
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return entries.size();
    }

    public void removeEntry(int position) {
        entries.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void restoreEntry(Entry entry, int position) {
        entries.add(position, entry);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public List<Entry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by myself. For some reason I set parameter `layout_width` of that textViews as `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`. I changed the value and everything started to work correctly.